# How can I change the fontsize of the mainmenu items in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

One would think that there would be a Font property for MainMenu, since there is one for just about everything else e.g. Buttons, Labels, etc.

Comment: Although Remy and Andreas gave you the answer, you should be aware that the menu font is a user-configuration option. It should be left up to the user to set it, and that's what happens by default - the VCL reads the values set by the user in Display Properties->Appearance->Advanced Appearance in the Menu item and uses that for the menu font size and name.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't mess around with this, but the standard menu font on a widescreen monitor can be a bit samll at times, especially in some 3rd party applications. The same in my application, as it is being skinned and the menu font size could be a tad small for some.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write, for instance,

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.MenuFont.Name := 'Arial Black';
end;
```

and make sure that the `OwnerDraw` property of your `TMainMenu` is set to `true`.

Comment: Many thanks. Next time I'll Google Screen instead of TScreen.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the TScreen.MenuFont property.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but exactly how do I use it? I've Googled but there are no examples, only your statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The TScreen.MenuFont property is a TFont.  Set its properties at run-time like you would any other Font property, ie: Screen.MenuFont.Size := ...;

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should have tried Googling Screen instead of TSCreen.

Comment: Not working good with RTL.