# Change edit control's standard context menu font size

Tags: windows, delphi

Can I change font size of a edit control's standard context menu or I should build my own menu that imitates it?

[image: Standard context menu]

Comment: Why do you need to change the font size of a single menu in your app (as opposed to all context menus)?

Comment: Please don't imitate - you're prone to miss details you're not aware of, like [access keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/inter-keyboard) which aren't underlined in your picture.

Comment: The menu font is a system-wide setting. You should not try to change it, or try to create your own. If the user wants a different size font, they can make that change themselves.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: Yes, you are right. I would like to change the font size in all context menus of the application (but not in all aplications of my Windows session :) )

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Still, I agree with AmigoJack and Ken White. But if you really insist, this is possible using dark magic (with quite a few unwanted side effects). I suspect that the least horrible solution is to create your own menu. I trust you are aware of https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760343/282848.